# Unable to grab complete Handlebars template from Javascript

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I am using Handlebars and AJAX to re-render template on every AJAX response. However, nothing is happening, neither template is rendered nor any error message is shown by browser. On little debugging, I found out that `javascript` is not grabbing complete hbs template.

Here is my Handlebars template:

```
<!--Template-->

<script id="careers-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <ul>
        {{#each careers_list}}
            <li class="mt-list-item">
                <div class="list-icon-container">
                    <button data-toggle="tooltip"
                            title="Add to Favorites"><i
                            class="fav-btn ion ion-ios-heart-outline font-red-intense"></i>
                    </button>
                </div>

                <div class="list-item-content">
                    <h3 class="uppercase">
                        {{this}}
                    </h3>
                </div>
            </li>
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
</script>
```

Here is console output of `source`:

```
<ul> </ul>
```

Here is my AJAX call:

```
$.ajax({
           url: '/dashboard/careers/get_careers_list',
           type: 'POST',
           contentType: 'application/json',
           data: JSON.stringify({category: category})
       }).done(function (data) {

           var container =  $("#career-detail-list");

           var source   = $("#careers-template").html();
           var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
           var list = template({careers_list: data});

           console.log(source);
           container.html(list);
       });
```

The AJAX return an `array of strings`.

Can anyone please help why `javascript` is not grabbing complete hbs template??

Answer (score 0):

The problem is careers_list is empty.

Check if its `this.careers_list` instead of just `careers_list`

Also send the key in quotes

```
var list = template({'careers_list':data})
```

Comment: careers_list is not empty. I have checked it in console. The `source` in javascript is not being grabbed completely.

Comment: @VaibhavAgarwal I highly doubt source is not being grabbed if you're getting `<ul></ul>`. data is most likely empty. Can you show a print of `console.log(data)`?

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande yes source is empty but data is not. I tried to grab the template from external source and it worked but when the template is inline, it is not grabbing the source.